# How do I exclude a <div> in html from being affected by jquery animation?

Tags: jquery

Like the title says, I need to exclude a  from being affected by a jquery script

Comment: Pretend like we're not sitting at your desk and can't see what plugins you're using and what sort of interference is taking place.

Comment: code please, so that i can know how exactly the code is being get conflicted with 2 jquery plugins

Comment: Note that the dock menu is old, it might not be compatible with recent browsers.

Comment: Please check your javascript console and tell us if any errors are showing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read up on the getting started section of the jQuery plugin authoring.  It explains about scoping your plugin:
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Getting_Started

Also, ensure you are appropriately namespacing: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Namespacing

and finally, you can fall back on noConflict:
http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

Answer (score 0):

I am not too experienced in JQuery so someone might come up with a better answer than I can,  but addressing the title of this post,  you could change the  that you don't want affected to another tag like  or .  Another solution would be to give the  you do want affected by the jquery an id that can be called on by the script.  Calling on just the  tag is too vague when it comes to a website.

I hope this helped.
I may have missed the question entirely though.  It was worth a try!